# Android Studio Multiplatform Development baseon PC and MAC through Google Drive

Tags: android, windows, macos

At present time,I develop  my android project at office by using Android Studio Windows Edition on PC and save project to GoogleDrive, so I can develop android project at home and office. I will develop iOS project in the future, I paln to buy a Mac Mini at home and using Xcode and Android Studio Mac Edition to develop iOS and Android Project Simultaneously. But I don't know whether the Android Studio Mac Edition could read the project which created by Android Studio Windows Edition which have saved on Google Drives  ?Is there anyone have tried this kind of development architecture  ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the exact same setup you describe, but I have started an Android project before on my PC running Windows 7 and transferred it to my iMac via flash drive. The project worked perfectly and I was able to continue to develop it on the iMac. You might see a message pop up when you first transfer it but Android Studio should be able to handle the transfer without any problems.